# Is it safe to use GitLab CI «protected» variables for secrets?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I haven't found any way to pass secret variables in GitLab CI pipelines except with so-called «protected» variables. Any other variables **can be revealed by any committer** as every commit/branch goes throw a pipeline and the code can be modified.

I don't like protected variables because they are too complicated. I need to grant access to some variable to certain people like I do in SQL-databases or Linux filesystems. Instead, I have to make a protected variable, a protected branch, a protected environment (premium feature). And I have to add the maintainer permission level to some users. And then (maybe) they will the only people to access my secret variables.

Also, I have no idea how are those variables stored. Usually, I use Hashicorp Vault and now GitLab is the weakest security point.

Is it safe enough?
Are there more reliable methods to keep secrets in CI pipelines?

Answer (score 4):

[issue 13784](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/13784) refers to an encryption at REST, so [the security is not... optimal](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/01/09/hacker_publishes_github_secret_key_hunter/)

There is an [epic opened](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/816) to improve that, and you can [setup an Vault integration](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/www-gitlab-com/issues/3777), but there is not one by default.
[Issue 61053](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/61053) is about solving that: "Vault integration for key/value secrets MVC"

> More and more teams are starting to store their secrets in [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/).
>   We should provide a secure way to fetch short-lived tokens from Vault that can be used at runtime by a job in a CI/CD pipeline.

This is for GitLab 12.3, Sept. 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer of @VonC, here is the general vision expressed by GitLab with regards to Secrets Management and various scenarios of integrating with Vault, including fully embedding it inside: https://about.gitlab.com/direction/release/secrets_management/